# Unexpected Modulus Operator Behavior in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, modulus

I have a list of usernames and database names (below). The 39th line is "AHernandez Sample ".

Here is my script code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i = 0;
my $n = 13;

while (<>) {
    s/Sample /Sample Basic/ unless ++$i % $n;
    print;
}
```

Here is how I'm calling the script: perl Test1.txt > Test3.txt.

Here's the odd part. The 39th line, or 4th instance, gets modified by the code. `Sample` becomes `Sample Basic`.Then the expected behavior of every 13th instance occurs. Why is the 4th instance of "Sample " being changed and then every 13th thereafter?

admin
AEluf Bane
AEluf PoiznIvy
AEluf MrFreeze
AEluf Demo
AEluf Sample
AEluf Sample_U
AEluf Samppart
AEluf Sampeast
AEluf ASOsamp
AEluf PFPSamp
AEluf SampApp
AGodfrey Bane
AGodfrey PoiznIvy
AGodfrey MrFreeze
AGodfrey Demo
AGodfrey Sample
AGodfrey Sample_U
AGodfrey Samppart
AGodfrey Sampeast
AGodfrey ASOsamp
AGodfrey PFPSamp
AGodfrey SampApp
AGold Bane
AGold PoiznIvy
AGold MrFreeze
AGold Demo
AGold Sample
AGold Sample_U
AGold Samppart
AGold Sampeast
AGold ASOsamp
AGold PFPSamp
AGold SampApp
AHernandez Bane
AHernandez PoiznIvy
AHernandez MrFreeze
AHernandez Demo
AHernandez Sample Basic
AHernandez Sample_U
AHernandez Samppart
AHernandez Sampeast
AHernandez ASOsamp
AHernandez PFPSamp
AHernandez SampApp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script tries to replace with `s///` on every 13-th line of the file (13,26,39,52,etc)

https://eval.in/81619

```
[line: 1; ( 1 % 13)=> 1; try_replace: no] admin
[line: 2; ( 2 % 13)=> 2; try_replace: no] AEluf Bane
[line: 3; ( 3 % 13)=> 3; try_replace: no] AEluf PoiznIvy
[line: 4; ( 4 % 13)=> 4; try_replace: no] AEluf MrFreeze
[line: 5; ( 5 % 13)=> 5; try_replace: no] AEluf Demo
[line: 6; ( 6 % 13)=> 6; try_replace: no] AEluf Sample
[line: 7; ( 7 % 13)=> 7; try_replace: no] AEluf Sample_U
[line: 8; ( 8 % 13)=> 8; try_replace: no] AEluf Samppart
[line: 9; ( 9 % 13)=> 9; try_replace: no] AEluf Sampeast
[line:10; (10 % 13)=>10; try_replace: no] AEluf ASOsamp
[line:11; (11 % 13)=>11; try_replace: no] AEluf PFPSamp
[line:12; (12 % 13)=>12; try_replace: no] AEluf SampApp
[line:13; (13 % 13)=> 0; try_replace:yes] AGodfrey Bane
[line:14; (14 % 13)=> 1; try_replace: no] AGodfrey PoiznIvy
[line:15; (15 % 13)=> 2; try_replace: no] AGodfrey MrFreeze
[line:16; (16 % 13)=> 3; try_replace: no] AGodfrey Demo
[line:17; (17 % 13)=> 4; try_replace: no] AGodfrey Sample
[line:18; (18 % 13)=> 5; try_replace: no] AGodfrey Sample_U
[line:19; (19 % 13)=> 6; try_replace: no] AGodfrey Samppart
[line:20; (20 % 13)=> 7; try_replace: no] AGodfrey Sampeast
[line:21; (21 % 13)=> 8; try_replace: no] AGodfrey ASOsamp
[line:22; (22 % 13)=> 9; try_replace: no] AGodfrey PFPSamp
[line:23; (23 % 13)=>10; try_replace: no] AGodfrey SampApp
[line:24; (24 % 13)=>11; try_replace: no] AGold Bane
[line:25; (25 % 13)=>12; try_replace: no] AGold PoiznIvy
[line:26; (26 % 13)=> 0; try_replace:yes] AGold MrFreeze
[line:27; (27 % 13)=> 1; try_replace: no] AGold Demo
[line:28; (28 % 13)=> 2; try_replace: no] AGold Sample
[line:29; (29 % 13)=> 3; try_replace: no] AGold Sample_U
[line:30; (30 % 13)=> 4; try_replace: no] AGold Samppart
[line:31; (31 % 13)=> 5; try_replace: no] AGold Sampeast
[line:32; (32 % 13)=> 6; try_replace: no] AGold ASOsamp
[line:33; (33 % 13)=> 7; try_replace: no] AGold PFPSamp
[line:34; (34 % 13)=> 8; try_replace: no] AGold SampApp
[line:35; (35 % 13)=> 9; try_replace: no] AHernandez Bane
[line:36; (36 % 13)=>10; try_replace: no] AHernandez PoiznIvy
[line:37; (37 % 13)=>11; try_replace: no] AHernandez MrFreeze
[line:38; (38 % 13)=>12; try_replace: no] AHernandez Demo
[line:39; (39 % 13)=> 0; try_replace:yes] AHernandez Sample BasicBasic
[line:40; (40 % 13)=> 1; try_replace: no] AHernandez Sample_U
[line:41; (41 % 13)=> 2; try_replace: no] AHernandez Samppart
[line:42; (42 % 13)=> 3; try_replace: no] AHernandez Sampeast
[line:43; (43 % 13)=> 4; try_replace: no] AHernandez ASOsamp
[line:44; (44 % 13)=> 5; try_replace: no] AHernandez PFPSamp
[line:45; (45 % 13)=> 6; try_replace: no] AHernandez SampApp
```

To replace every n-th occurrence of string:

```
while (<>) {
    ++$i if /Sample /;
    s/Sample /Sample Basic/ unless $i % $n;
    print;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. So how would I get it to do every 13th instance of the string "Sample " instead of every 13 lines? Thanks!